# What is the best practice for using same project for both app and library in android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-3.0

I created android application and need to converted it to library.
I changed module build.gradle file by changing

```
id 'com.android.application'
```

to

```
id 'com.android.library'
```

and it works great.
But for adding new features a need to convert it again to app.
I can use 2 files build.gradle and build.gradle.app and change between them,
but the question is what is the best practice for managing both app and library in the same project

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your library, then you need to have a project in which there will be two modules. The first (**library**) is the library itself and the second module(**sample**) is the project to which you link this library. In sample you can check all the new functions of your library.

**library** module - `id 'com.android.library'`

**sample** module - `id 'com.android.application'`

and inside sample **build.gradle** add this, to connect the library

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation project(':library')
...
}
```

This is how the project structure looks like

[image]